# How to write to HDFS programmatically?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

So after 36 hours of experimenting with this and that, I have finally managed to get a cluster up and running but now I am confused how I can write files to it using Java? A tutorial said this program should be used but I don't understand it at all and it doesn't work as well.

```
public class FileWriteToHDFS {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //Source file in the local file system
    String localSrc = args[0];
    //Destination file in HDFS
    String dst = args[1];

    //Input stream for the file in local file system to be written to HDFS
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localSrc));

    //Get configuration of Hadoop system
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    System.out.println("Connecting to -- "+conf.get("fs.defaultFS"));

    //Destination file in HDFS
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dst), conf);
    OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(dst));

    //Copy file from local to HDFS
    IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, true);

    System.out.println(dst + " copied to HDFS");

    }
}
```

My confusion is how does this piece of code identify specifics of my cluster? How will it know where the masternode is and where the slavenodes are?

Furthermore when I run this code and provide some local file in source and leave destination blank/or provide a file name only the program writes the file back to my local storage and not the location that I defined as storage space for my namenodes and datanodes. Should I be providing this path manually? How does this work? Please suggest some blog that can help me understand it better or can get working with a smallest example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you'll need to add some Hadoop libraries to your classpath. Without those, no, that code won't work.

> How will it know where the masternode is and where the slavenodes are?

From the `new Configuration();` and subsequent `conf.get("fs.defaultFS")`.

It reads the core-site.xml of the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable and returns the address of the namenode. The client only needs to talk to the namenode to receive the locations of the datanodes, from which file blocks are written to

> the program writes the file back to my local storage

It's not clear where you've configured the filesystem, but the default is `file://`, your local disk. You change this in the core-site.xml. If you follow the Hadoop documentation, the pseudo distributed cluster setup mentions this

It's also not very clear why you need your own Java code when simply `hdfs dfs -put` will do the same thing

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. Well I need to do this in Java because it is an academic project to create a distributed environment for given layout. HDFS is simply 1 component and I want to extend this code to accept files from primary application and store them to HDFS.

Comment: And yes I did configured the file system in the core-site.xml to be: hadoop.tmp.dir -> /home/hduser/bin/hdata. but instead to storing the files at this location it creates a local copy where the code is executed from. I am not sure why.

Comment: Ok I think I figured out the issue but don't know how to resolve it. I tried the command you mentioned "hdfs dfs -put" and it returned following error "No such filed or directory: 'hdfs://master:9000/user/hduser'"

Comment: You must first create an HDFS user folder for you to do anything as the `hduser` account

Comment: ok so I did that and I am able to store files to cluster now using the hdfs dfs -put command but the problem with the java code is still there. Also is it possible to store files to location other than user/hduser?

Comment: `hdfs dfs -put` takes a full path. For example, `hdfs dfs -put /my/special/directory`... I don't know what issues you're having with the Java code... ClassNotFound, for example? What `args` did you give?

Comment: Hi Sorry for getting back to you late on this one. I am going to close this question as I was experimenting here and there and picked few libraries from here and few from there. I have posted a new query, please can you have a look? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823715/hadoop-hdfs-write-operation-programmatically