# Hadoop HDFS Write Operation Programmatically

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I asked a similar question a while back but then I had not idea what I was talking about. I am posting this question with further details and to the point queries.

So I have set up hadoop cluster with namenode and 2 datanodes. I am using hadoop 2.9.0. I ran the command hdfs dfs -put "SomeRandomFile" and it seems to be working ok. The only confusion I have here is why does it store my file to /user/hduser/ path? I didn't specify this path anywhere in configurations so how is it building this path on hdfs?

Furthermore I created a small java program to do the same thing. I created a simple eclipse project and wrote following lines:

```
public static boolean fileWriteHDFS(InputStream input, String fileName) {   
    try {
        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hduser");

        //Get Configuration of Hadoop system
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
        //conf.get("fs.defaultFS");     

        //Extract destination path
        URI uri = URI.create(DESTINATION_PATH+fileName);
        Path path = new Path(uri);

        //Destination file in HDFS
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(uri, conf); //.get(conf);

        //Check if the file already exists
        if (fs.exists(path))
        {
            //Write appropriate error to log file and return.
            return false;
        }

        //Create an Output stream to the destination path
        FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(path);

        //Copy file from input steam to HDFSs
        IOUtils.copyBytes(input, out, 4096, true);

        //Close all the file descriptors
        out.close();
        fs.close();
        //All went perfectly as planned
        return true;    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Something went wrong
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I added following three hadoop libraries:

> /home/hduser/bin/hadoop-2.9.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.9.0.jar
>   /home/hduser/bin/hadoop-2.9.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.9.0-tests.jar
>   /home/hduser/bin/hadoop-2.9.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.9.0.jar

As you can see my hadoop installation location is /home/hduser/bin/hadoop-2.9.0/... When I run this code it throws an exception. i.e.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ctc/wstx/io/InputBootstrapper
at com.ws.filewrite.fileWrite.fileWriteHDFS(fileWrite.java:21)
at com.ws.main.listenerService.main(listenerService.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ctc.wstx.io.InputBootstrapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Specifically the exception is thrown at the lie:

> Configuration conf = new Configuration();

Am I missing something here? What is causing this problem? I am completely new to HDFS so pardon me it is obvious problem.

Comment: First, you don't need `-tests`, secondly, there are other libraries *those* JARs depend on. Suggestion: Use Maven, not manually adding JAR files to your classpath

Comment: "*why does it store my file to /user/hduser/ path*" ... Because that is the default behavior of the CLI `dfs -put` command

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks mate. I am not familiar with Maven can you suggest some links that can enhance my knowledge in this regard?

Comment: http://www.allprogrammingtutorials.com/tutorials/reading-writing-files-in-hdfs-using-java-api.php

Comment: Yes, We have faced same issue in Hadoop 3.2.1
I used below link code for uploading sample

https://javadeveloperzone.com/hadoop/java-read-write-files-hdfs-example/

Comment: Meet the same issue, have you figured out how to solve this? @UsamaZafar

Answer (score 2):

I faced error
`NoClassDefFoundError: com/ctc/wstx/io/InputBootstrapper`
when i was fixing the vulnerability in hadoop-commons. Hadoop-commons 3.3.4 internally uses woodstox-core old version which is vulnerable. After excluding the woodstox-core from hadoop-commons it starts throwing mentioned error.
After adding latest version of woodstox-core and stax2-api, error resolved.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

hadoop 2.9 dependencies are not compatible with hadoop 2.6.

i had encountered the same situation, and try to find the dependency jar. that's difficult, and may another jar miss in the next time...

so, i use Maven to manager dependencies.

you just append this two dependency, problem will be solved.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure where the question mentioned Hadoop 2.6

Comment: still find this Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ctc.wstx.io.InputBootstrapper

Comment: @Bargitta I was able to fix the issue by adding these 2 dependencies, /com/fasterxml/woodstox/woodstox-core/6.2.3/woodstox-core-6.2.3.jar, org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.2.1/stax2-api-4.2.1.jar