# How can i fix InputBootStrapper error in eclipse for runnig Hadoop program?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

How can i fix it ?
This code is Hadoop WordCount example in JAVA.
I have added the external JARs and this is not a compile time issue,
When i have tried o run the program this is happening.
The input and out put arguments are set.
All the mangers are up and running.

Hadoop version 2.9.0

Java version 1.8.0

Eclipse Oxygen

OS Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

What could be the issue?

wordcount.java

```
package mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class wordcount {

public static class TokenizerMapper
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
  }
}
}

public static class IntSumReducer
   extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int sum = 0;
  for (IntWritable val : values) {
    sum += val.get();
  }
  result.set(sum);
  context.write(key, result);
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
job.setJarByClass(wordcount.class);
job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

Console(Error)

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ctc/wstx/io/InputBootstrapper
    at mapreduce.wordcount.main(wordcount.java:51)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.ctc.wstx.io.InputBootstrapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Unclear where that class is trying to be loaded from. This code looks like it'll run fine. Eclipse isn't needed here, so try to compile the code without it. Also, it's easier to use Maven or Gradle than manually adding JAR files

Comment: My objective is to export the JAR using eclipse. Then i will execute the the mapreduce operation using that JAR through the terminal(Ubuntu). My hadoop is preforming perfectly with the existing JARs. But i want to build my own JAR for the mapreduce operation.
I failed to export JAR because of this error issue.
Please recommendations me the way i can export JAR.

Comment: As I said, if you use Maven or Gradle, it'll generate a JAR for you from the command line . And that doesn't require you using Eclipse (which I've never had good luck generating JAR files from)

Comment: As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/q/47823715/2308683 The issue is probably the versions of the JARs you added do not match your Hadoop installation

Comment: This time i have used maven ,
and its gives me ther error code like, 

    hduser@asif:/home/asif/eclipse-workspace/yyy$
    mvn clean install(command)
  
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default- 
    clean) on project yyy: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete 
    /home/asif/eclipse-workspace/yyy/target/test- 
    classes/com/ishtiaqasif/hadoop/yyy/AppTest.class -> [Help 1]

Comment: See FAQ section about this error https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/faq.html#On_Windows_I_got_Unable_to_delete_directory._What_s_wrong

Answer (score 1):

For me missing jar was this: `hadoop-client-runtime.jar`. Adding that additional dependency from Maven solved issue.

As a side note below is a list of my dependencies (I'm using SBT/Scala):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client-api" % "3.3.1",
  "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" %  "1.2",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.35",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client-runtime" % "3.3.1"
)
```

This link helped me to look at right direction: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33343